# reusing a template from existing git project

Tags: git, heroku

I'm looking to take an existing git repository where I have some code, download it, complete detach it from the existing project, and then make those files the only files of another existing git repo.

SO I want Files from Git A, and then overwrite Git b repo to only contain those files.

The reason I don't want to have the files from git b is because they're autocreated, and git A is an existing project that is going to serve as template, but it cannot just be a branch out of git A because the other project needs its own repo entirely.

I'm thinking that I need to do a checkout of the newest git a commit, but from there I don't see what's going to happen.

I hope I made myself clear. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you would like to eliminate some autogenerated files from your history. Checkout `git filter-branch` to make that happen and keep your history.

If you don't care about the history copy the files you want and start a new repository.

Comment: I would start a new repo, except the repo is all that is used from my webserver. I can't start a new repo since that would be a different webapp essentially.

Comment: Then you can force push of master. That essentially will replace what was there.